# Execute other server script on the page which called through ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, remote-server

I have a situation;

I'm calling PHP page through AJAX which require to execute a script on other server which has the email server rights. To be more specific on PHP page after Entering data in Database I have to access the Email server with certain parameters in Query String.

On index.php  page i have submit button which enters the data in database through AJAX call and then have to send an email to the user for information.
but for email i need to execute PHP script on other server which have Email server access.

CLIENT SIDE

```
$.ajax({
          url:'vpms/server/updating.php',
          type:'POST',
          data:formvalues,
          success: function(data) {  

                  closelightbox('black_overlay','vendorfeedback',ref-1,'CLOSE');
                  }
          });


IN updating.php
enter code here



 if($_POST['Type']=='SUBMITRATING')
   {

$sql->Query("INSERT INTO vpms_procurement(`prno`,`vn`,`category`,`paymentterms`,`c1`,`delivery`,`c2`,`communication`,`c3`,`dated`,emaildate ) VALUES('$_POST[PRNO]','$_POST[$vendor]','$_POST[$category]','$_POST[$payment]','$_POST[$payment_txt]','$_POST[$delivery]','$_POST[$delivery_txt]','$_POST[$response]','$_POST[$response_txt]',NOW(),'$_POST[$date]')");

}
$enc=Autoloader::encrypt(serialize($array));     
 // Sending request to other server for email   
 header("Location: 10.89.6.2/managerConfirmation.php?token=$enc"); //      This is not possible through ajax call
 //OR 
 exec("10.89.6.2/managerConfirmation.php?token=$enc")   
 }
```

Options which I may think of.

1. Using exec("PHP script?q=value");
2. Or on success of Ajax call make another call through JSONP to access remoteserver.

But I don't know how practical these options are, because I'm also using encrypted data in query string.

Comment: well you can't do what youre asking with php unless you refresh your page so that rules out php's exec function.  You need ajax.  What ajax code have you tried?  what problems do you have with it?

Comment: Your question is not clear, it is not possible to answer. Please try to defined more clearly the requirements, especially what 'remote server' referes to. Please don't write additional comments, edit your question above.

Comment: Well i was trying `Header(Location:Remotr Adress?querystring)` to access remote page, but then i came to know in ajax call redirection is not possible; WHY `exec()` will not work here?

Comment: php does not and cannot use ajax.  ajax is executed serverside (e.g. thru javascript 99.999% of the time) and php completes its execution b4 anything is sent to client's broswer.  ajax makes requests to server from client bower.  perhaps this link wil help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832733/server-side-vs-client-side-ajax-loading

Comment: i have edited my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i had to go with option of another ajax call , but i wanted to share a strange case.
It might help someone.

I used Ajax call which had no Callback and each request also had the failure message

**"XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'Remote server address' Origin http://mystuff.local is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"**

but strangely each request also Succeeded with the delivery of email..

Comment: Above Error Washed out by putting `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` on top of requested page

Answer (score 1):

your code is vulnerable to sql injection you need to escape all get and post

send use ajax call on successful return of first ajax call

Comment: my encryption menthod is handling with sql injection threat

Answer (score 0):

Use 2nd Ajax call on 1st successful ajax response.

```
$.ajax({
      url:'vpms/server/updating.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:formvalues,
      success: function(return_data) {  

              //Make 2nd ajax call here and run the remote script
              enc = return_data ;
                 $.ajax({
                  url:'10.89.6.2/managerConfirmation.php?token='+enc,
                  type:'POST',
                  data:anything,
                  success: function(data) {  

                          closelightbox('black_overlay','vendorfeedback',ref-1,'CLOSE');

                          }
                  });

              }
      });
```